# Unable to use sys.stdout.flush() to replace print "%s\r" % i for a spinning cursor animation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin, sys

I have been trying to implement a spinning cursor as a part of a game I am developing

```
t=1
while t<100:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i
        sys.stdout.flush()
    t=t+1
```

This does not work as part of a larger code whereas it works standalone even without `sys.stdout.flush()`

Whats the deal? I use Python 2.7 with Cygwin in Windows environment.

Answer (score 2):

`print` writes a newline to stdout after writing the desired text. Write the line with `sys.stdout.write()` instead:

```
while t<100:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        sys.stdout.write("%s\r" % i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    t=t+1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/ (pip install progressbar). 
It supports multiple bar styles. For a simple spinning cursor, try:

```
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=['Working: ', AnimatedMarker()])
for i in pbar((i for i in range(50))):
    time.sleep(.08)
```

More examples: https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/source/browse/examples.py